# CSV download issue

Tags: html, csv, download

I am trying to download one csv file in my html file with anchor tag. Its getting downloaded only as .txt file. Tried few things like download attribute but nothing working.
Please help

```html
<a href="https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx/20140815-111929455-000001-00030-1658.csv?__gda__=1440109223_83f5e968923d7f99b30844358fe4ce4c" download="temp.csv" type="text/csv" target="_blank"/>
```

Comment: Have you tested it on different browsers?

Comment: Mainly my requirement is on chrome only. But yes i tired on other browsers as well But its opening in new window there. In other browsers i am not even able to get the download.

Answer (score 0):

What about removing the file name from the download attribute and adding it to your href attribute? Doing it that way should eliminate the need for a target and type as well.

```
<a href="/path/temp.csv" download>link</a>
```

I haven't tried this with a csv file before, but it's worked for me with images after checking out a [w3schools example](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp).